# Access baseUrl() in View Helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Simple ZF question:

How can the `baseUrl()` be accessed in a View Helper without passing it as an argument?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract` methods. If your view helper extends `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`, then you can use the internal `$view` member to access the view from which the helper was called. The solution Dickie proposes would fail if your layout view would be different from your action's view. It also introduces new class, that is not needed every time.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I have seen use cases where "view from layout" approach will fail silently. Also Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance() will return NULL if layout was not initialized with MVC support.

Answer (score 4):

You want to access a view helper from within another view helper?

Off the top of my head you will need to get the view object first:

`$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();`

Now you can call baseUrl() (e.g. `echo $view->baseUrl();`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$this->view->baseUrl()
```